# cross compiler to linux (build and host) to freebsd

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, freebsd

I was trying to compile a gcc cross compiler for linux x86_64 (build and host) to freebsd x86_64.
I tried to follow this http://marcelog.github.io/articles/articles.html and then some other guides around the web, but I continue to get this:
Code:

```
...
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nick/Scaricati/build-gcc/x86_64-freebsd10.1/libgcc'
DEFINES='' HEADERS='' \
   ../../../gcc-4.9.2/libgcc/mkheader.sh > tmp-libgcc_tm.h
/bin/bash ../../../gcc-4.9.2/libgcc/../move-if-change tmp-libgcc_tm.h libgcc_tm.h
echo timestamp > libgcc_tm.stamp
/home/nick/Scaricati/build-gcc/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/nick/Scaricati/build-gcc/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/cross/x86_64-freebsd10.1/bin/ -B/usr/local/cross/x86_64-freebsd10.1/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/cross/x86_64-freebsd10.1/include -isystem /usr/local/cross/x86_64-freebsd10.1/sys-include  -g -O2 -O2  -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition  -isystem ./include  -fpic -pthread -g -DIN_LIBGCC2 -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector -Dinhibit_libc  -fpic -pthread -I. -I. -I../.././gcc -I../../../gcc-4.9.2/libgcc -I../../../gcc-4.9.2/libgcc/. -I../../../gcc-4.9.2/libgcc/../gcc -I../../../gcc-4.9.2/libgcc/../include  -DHAVE_CC_TLS  -o _muldi3.o -MT _muldi3.o -MD -MP -MF _muldi3.dep -DL_muldi3 -c ../../../gcc-4.9.2/libgcc/libgcc2.c -fvisibility=hidden -DHIDE_EXPORTS
In file included from ../../../gcc-4.9.2/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:44:0,
  from ../../../gcc-4.9.2/libgcc/libgcc2.c:27:
/home/nick/Scaricati/build-gcc/gcc/include/stddef.h:56:24: fatal error: sys/_types.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/_types.h>
  ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:463: recipe for target '_muldi3.o' failed
make[2]: *** [_muldi3.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nick/Scaricati/build-gcc/x86_64-freebsd10.1/libgcc'
Makefile:12757: recipe for target 'all-target-libgcc' failed
make[1]: *** [all-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nick/Scaricati/build-gcc'
Makefile:869: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

this is the lasts logs of make process of gcc-4.9.2 sources with TARGET=x86_64-freebsd10.1

what I'm doing wrong? Any ideas?

****** EDIT ******

This is the configuration used:

```
configure --without-headers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-nls --enable-libssp --enable-gold --enable-ld --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-libgomp
```

Comment: it is probably of interest what configure args you used.

Comment: You are right, I just edited the thread.

Comment: the mailing list `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org` might be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thank you, they helped me to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I didn't set up properly sysroot.

I had to dowload (or take it from a build and working system) the target system on my machine (in my case freebsd, so I got base.txz, lib32.txz and to be sure (but I think that they are not necessary) also src.txz and kernel.txz, and then I was able to set `--with-sysroot` in configuration process of binutils and gcc sources, and then run

```
$ make
```

and

```
# make install
```

for binutils and gcc and finally I got my toolchain!